# How to check the incoming link in PHP

Tags: php, html, href, http-referer

I am writing a PHP module where I need to check if the incoming link is coming from a particular page.

I have 2 pages :

1. Services.php  : 
   I have a `href` something like this

> ```
> <a href="product.php">SUBSCRIBE NOW</a>
> ```

1. Product.php : Here I check, if the incoming link is from services.php using the following code :

> ```
> $ref_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
> $refData = parse_url($ref_url);
> if (strpos($refData['path'],'services.php') !== false ) 
> {
>   // Subscribe_Module
> }
> else
> {
>   //Other
> }
> ```

This works fine, as long as the user clicks on the

> ```
> <a href="product.php">SUBSCRIBE NOW</a>
> ```

However, there is a side effect, when the user is on services.php page and then clicks on product.php on the header, it executes, the `subscribe_module` in the PHP. Any idea, how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please read your own sentence and try to rewrite it since it does not make much sense: *However, this is a side effect, when the user if the user is on services.php page and then clicks on product.php on the header, it executes, the subscribe_module in the PHP*

Comment: So what is it you want it to do? I don't see the difference in your question, the user clicks on `products.php`..

Comment: It's as easy as: `<a href="product.php?from=Services.php">SUBSCRIBE NOW</a>` - then checking if the request has that data with it, here for example by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: @AndreschSerj, I am exteremly sorry, I did not pay much attention while posting the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @skzryzg, Thanks for pointing it out. Looks like, you are not one of those. The Americans that I know of, try to help people in need and not ridicule.

Comment: Since this went Off Topic anyway: I'm not a native english speaker and i do not mind gramar mistakes or anything like that. Thou if a sentence makes no sense whatsoever, i assume it needs improvement ;-p
And the question still makes very little sense

Answer (score 1):

Simple, Nest another loop inside `If` :)

```
if (strpos($refData['path'],'services.php') !== false ) 
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == abc/services.php)
  {
     //call services function
  }
  else
  {
    // Subscribe_Module
  }

}
else
{
  //Other
}
```